# why setImmediate function executes after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, callstack, event-loop

```
setImmediate(() => {
    console.log("set immediate function calling")
})
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("setTime out function")
}, 1000)
for (let i = 0; i <= 10000000000; i++) {

}
console.log("loop end")
```

The result is:

```
loop end
setTime out function
set immediate function calling
```

Comment: Does the behavior change if you change the timeout to 0 or something much larger?  Per https://nodejs.org/en/learn/asynchronous-work/understanding-setimmediate both execute in the micrtask queue which suggest to me that `setTimeout()` ends up first.

Comment: If you really want to know, then read the "setImmediate() vs setTimeout()" section in this article: https://nodejs.org/en/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick first and then read the rest of the article.  You will find that it all depends upon what phase the event loop was in when the code was first initiated and perhaps on some other conditions too.  My summary is, don't write code that depends on this level of minute detail of scheduling knowledge.  If it matters what order these execute in, then write your code to control that independently of how the internal scheduling works.

Comment: Note that if executed as ESM you will have a different result (because the main script is executed in the microtask phase in this case).

Answer (score -1):

`setimmediate` executes its callback function after the current event loop finishes. The current event includes everything like displaying running a loop or another browser operation.

Also note `setimmediate` is a depreciated

Comment: If I read the documentation right both do so it doesn't explain the relative order of the two tasks.

Comment: Where are you seeing that setImmediate is deprecated in nodejs (the question is tagged for nodejs)?  I see the nodejs doc for it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#setimmediatecallback-args) with no mention of it being deprecated.

Comment: @jfriend00 the question is also tagged with javascript

Comment: Nodejs is Javascript.,  This question is not about javascript in the browser, it's about javascript in nodejs.